# CGContextShowTextAtPoint how to write text in horizontal from bottom to top?

Tags: ios4, ios5, core-graphics

I would like to write a text in CGContext horizontally from bottom to top? I did the following.

```
 CGContextSelectFont(cgContext, "Arial", 8, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
 CGContextSetTextMatrix(cgContext, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation  (M_PI /2));
 CGContextShowTextAtPoint(cgContext, xval, yval, "transd", 6);
```

The text is made horizontally, but it displays the text reversed. how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

CGContextSetTextMatrix(cgContext, CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0));

instead of:

CGContextSetTextMatrix(cgContext, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation  (M_PI /2));

works for me, hopefully it will work for you